# Scrolling to display overflowing element on hover in javascript

Tags: javascript

In a web app I have a `div` with tooltips that are displayed only when hovering over certain objects of the page. These tooltips can overflow out of the div. When this happens, the scrollbars appear on the page as expected.
The issue is that the user cannot scroll with the mouse, because doing so moves the mouse out of the hovering element, so the tooltip disappear, and the window resizes down to the original size (so the scrollbars disappear too).

Here is a mock example of a similar behaviour :
[image]

I tried to use [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) for putting the object into the view, but again this works for a fraction of seconds, as the automatic scrolling of the page to put the element into view moves the mouse out of the hovering element and causes the tooltip to disappear.

Is there a way to always keep the biggest frame size ? This way the user can scroll into the right view before hovering over the elements so that they are displayed entirely.

Comment: Can you share your code? I'm not sure but looks like you didn't set the max-width

Comment: @Rajibkarmaker actually it's just an iframe that loads the external page with the tooltips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by using [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver).

I defined this function in the source of the web app :

```js
parent.set_size = function(height, width) {
    const iframe = document.getElementById('your-iframe');
    iframe.style.height = height + "px";
    iframe.style.width = width + "px";
}
```

and then in the page loaded in the iframe I defined something similar to :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // set the div which has a dynamic size depending on whether or not the tooltip are displayed
    var map_div = document.getElementById("map")
    // set the initial size
    parent.set_size(map_div.scrollHeight, map_div.scrollWidth);
    var max_height = map_div.scrollHeight;
    var max_width = map_div.scrollWidth;
    // when the size changes, keep the biggest size
    var ro = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
        for (let entry of entries) {
            max_width = Math.max(entry.target.scrollWidth, max_width);
            max_height = Math.max(entry.target.scrollHeight, max_height);
            parent.set_size(max_height, max_width);
        }
    });
    ro.observe(map_div);
});
```

This way the iframe always keep the biggest size it get to, which allows scrolling to the correct position before displaying the tooltip.